# Weird behaviour using IF statements and structs in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, cell

The output is always two values when it is supposed to be only 1 ..

s is a struct where

```
1x1024 struct array with fields:
    ID
    s1
    s2
    s3
    s4
    PB1
    PB2
    PB3
    PB4
    eG
    next
```

I have the following loop :

```
for t=1:length(s)

if s(t).eG==0


 if s(t).s1==1

    if s(t).PB1==0
        slackp(t)=0; 
    elseif s(t).PB1==1
        slackp(t)=350;
    elseif s(t).PB1==2
        slackp(t)=600;
    elseif s(t).PB1==3
        slackp(t)=750;
    end
end

 if s(t).s2==1

    if s(t).PB2==0
        slackp2(t)=0; 
    elseif s(t).PB2==1
        slackp2(t)=500;
    elseif s(t).PB2==2
        slackp2(t)=620;
    elseif s(t).PB2==3
        slackp2(t)=785;
    end

  end
 end
end
```

However I notice that at the following statement at t=2

```
        elseif s(t).PB1==1
        slackp(t)=350;
```

It always prints

```
 slackp(1)=[0 350]
```

The error carries forward and multiple other entries have 0 alongside with them !! Why is this happening ? I am just trying to store 350, I don't want a 0 there !

I tried debugging the problem, and realised that whenever s1 is not =1, it will print a 0. It shouldn't. If s1 is not `1` then just skip the IF statement. Same goes for s2.

Comment: 'However I notice that at the following statement at t=2'. This is because `slackp(t)=350;` is doing `slackp(2)=350;` This means it's setting the second element to 350.

Comment: If slackp is empty, then you add an element to slackp(2) you'll get a 2 element array where the first element is 0. Is that's what's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get around this problem you can use a different variable to index slackp than to index s. For example:

```
clear all
s(1).s1 = 0;
s(1).PB1 = 2;
s(1).PB2 = 2;
s(1).s2 = 0;
s(2).s1 = 1;
s(2).s2 = 1;
s(2).PB1 = 1;
s(2).PB2 = 3;
s(3).s1 = 1;
s(3).PB1 = 2;
s(3).s2 = 1;
s(3).PB2 = 2;

index1 = 1;
index2 = 1;
for t=1:length(s)
if s(t).s1==1
    if s(t).PB1==0
        slackp(inde1x)=0; 
         index1 = index1 + 1;
    elseif s(t).PB1==1
        slackp(index1)=350;
         index1 = index1 + 1;
    elseif s(t).PB1==2
        slackp(index1)=600;
         index1 = index1 + 1;
    elseif s(t).PB1==3
        slackp(index1)=750;
         index1 = index1 + 1;
    end

end 


if s(t).s2==1

    if s(t).PB2==0
        slackp2(index2)=0; 
        index2 = index2 + 1;
    elseif s(t).PB2==1
        slackp2(index2)=500;
        index2 = index2 + 1;
    elseif s(t).PB2==2
        slackp2(index2)=620;
        index2 = index2 + 1;
    elseif s(t).PB2==3
        slackp2(index2)=785;
        index2 = index2 + 1;
    end

    end

 end
```

Will give you:

```
slackp =
```

350   600

```
slackp2 =
```

785   620

Alternately, you can use end + 1 to index your output array, like this:

```
slackp = [];
for t=1:length(s)
    if s(t).s1==1
        if s(t).PB1==0
            slackp(end + 1)=0; 
        elseif s(t).PB1==1
            slackp(end + 1)=350;
        elseif s(t).PB1==2
            slackp(end + 1)=600;
        elseif s(t).PB1==3
            slackp(end + 1)=750;
        end
    end 
 end
```

Comment: This is not working for me, I am not sure why. I updated the code, I debugged it further and realised that this only happens when there is an extra IF statement.

Comment: What do you mean extra if state? Are you using a separate index for slackp2?

Comment: No I'm using the same index value for the whole for loop. an extra IF statement that I added in the updated question. It's `if s(t).eG==0` .. Apparently If I don't use that, the values are printed and stored correctly, otherwise, the extra zeros start appearing.

Comment: Or maybe the IF statement doesn't do anything, I am not sure, but the result still prints with extra zeros.

Comment: Ok, I misinterpreted your question. If you never want extra zeros, you need to increment index only when you add something to slackp.I've updated my answer.

Comment: So every variable must have it's own index number ?

Comment: Each output array needs it's own index number. Alternately, you can initialize slackp and use slackp(end + 1) to add elements to the end. I'll update my answer to include an example.

Comment: The alternative way is exactly the same thing ? What does `end` do ?

Comment: Yes. It does the same thing.  end is an index to the last element of the array.